# node_modules appears empty, you may need to run `npm install`

Tags: angular, serve

I have cloned an Angular 4 project from git.

When I go to the root folder of the project and executed `ng serve`.

I am getting following error:

```
node_modules appears empty, you may need to run `npm install`
```

How can I fix the above error?

Comment: so did you run "npm install" where your package.json is?

Comment: I have fixed above error by doing npm install command.

Comment: Note that it's useful to *read* the error message, rather than just copy-pasting it into Stack Overflow.

Comment: My doubt is , I have already installed npm globally, why is it not taking that one. Should I install npm for each and every project.

Comment: Sorry @jonrsharpe, I am new to npm and node.

Comment: To install npm globally only enables you to run its commands from every directory, node modules are always project specific. There for package.json has to be always present in the root directory of your project.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Run `npm install` from the root of the project. If you're on a mac then you may want to run `sudo npm install` in case some if the package installations require elevated permissions. If it has submodules then leave a comment below and I'll update this answer to include how to deal with those. No use in confusing this answer with that unless you hit it.

Comment: I hate to break the chain here, but I was getting the same issue and `npm install` or `sudo npm install` wasn't working.  The key is to `sudo rm -rf node_modules/` FIRST, then `npm install` will work fine.  Make sure to `sudo` remove

Comment: If you had to delete the node_modules folder first then it existed. And based on the command you used it wasn't empty. What symptom did you have?

Answer (score 1):

If it's saying `node_module is empty`, it means it's not getting the path.

First of all, check the path. Go to that path using the `cd` command, such as:

```
cd C:\Windows\UrProjectName
```

After that, run `ng serve` in node using the Command Prompt (Windows).

Comment: That advice to check the path by cd'ing to the project directory is what solved the problem for me.  I was still in the parent directory after creating the Angular project via `ng new`.  I needed to change to the newly created project directory before calling `ng serve`

Answer (score 0):

Open the directory where your project is using:

```
cd Project_Name
```

Then, run the following command:

```
npm install
```

After that, you can then easily run the `ng g component` command.

Answer (score -1):

In this situation you should right click the `app.component.html` module, then click *"open in terminal"*.

After the terminal is opened at the bottom, all you need to do is type the following command:

```
ng serve
```

It should now work properly. Every time you run the project and use this method, you will be able to avoid these types of errors.