# How to resolve "node_modules appears empty, you may need to run `npm install"?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have cloned a project from GitHub and started a Git Bash from the root folder. I tried to start the project by typing `ember serve`, but I got the following error:

```
node_modules appears empty, you may need to run `npm install`
```

In the Git Bash, I also typed `npm install`, but [nothing happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52299309/some-vulnerabilities-require-your-attention-to-resolve-git-bash).

I also read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47097772/node-modules-appears-empty-you-may-need-to-run-npm-install) but it didn't help me.

Comment: Assuming your link for "nothing happens" is relevant to your situation, did you try following the directions and running `npm audit fix`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yeah , I tried `npm audit fix` but it says you have to fix it manually .

Comment: it means the project is severely outdated. Post an issue on their github repository and copy the output from `npm audit` so they can update their dependencies and get the project working again. The fact that `npm audit fix` requires manual intervention means that the dependencies which have vulnerabilities can only be updated with non-backwards-compatible changes.

Answer (score 2):

You must open the Command Prompt in the directory that contains the `package.json` file. Then, run `npm install` in the Command Prompt.

Comment: Should I use cmd or GitBash .

Comment: Till now I am doing the same procedure use GitBash but nothing happenes .

Comment: nothing happen ? You should run npm start / ember serve or something like that after "npm install' done

Comment: @everyBit I have tried in both CMD(administrator) and GitBash but nothing works .